# Pentaho Kettle, update value

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I would like to update a value some values stored in a table with some values from a file.
I know exactly which row to update as in my update file I've got the id of the row.
I've tried the different "update" steps but they don't seem to do exactly what I want.
For example, if I only select the data I need to update, kettle deletes the others fields.

Could you please explain me how to update only one field of my db ?

Thanks

Arnaud

Comment: Just remove the fields you don't want to update from your update list. Select the field and press DEL.

Comment: Hi Brian, 

That strange because this is exactly what I did. But when I do that, kettle automatically empty the fields that are not in my update list.

Comment: What kettle version is that? it definitely DOESNT do that. Please paste an image of the transformation and the step configuration, there's something wrong somewhere.

Comment: Hi Codek, in fact it's not really pentaho but I'm using a GIS version pf pentaho called GeoKettle.